# Set ImageView to be GONE when the retrieved JSON object is null

Tags: android, json, imageview

I store all of my values into a JSON object and when the value for my image is null, I want my ImageView to be GONE.

I will firstly get my JSON object, then view it on a ListView where there are a TextView and  an ImageView. However, it is optional for the user to input an image, thus there are possibility for the ImageView to be empty.
Therefore, I want the ImageView visibility to be GONE if it is empty.

Here's what I tried, but failed:

Event.java

```
public class Event {
    public String id;
    public String logo;
    public String companyName;
    public String description;
    public String eventImage;

    public Event(){
    }

    public Event(String id, String logo, String companyName, String description, String eventImage){
        this.id = id;
        this.logo = logo;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.description = description;
        this.eventImage = eventImage;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEventImage() {
        return eventImage;
    }

    public void setEventImage(String eventImage) {
        this.eventImage = eventImage;
    }

    public String getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }

    public void setLogo(String logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Event> events) {
        super(context, 0, events);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Event event = getItem(position);

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, parent, false);


        TextView clubName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clubName);
        TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        ImageView clubImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        ImageView eventImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventImg);

        clubName.setText(event.companyName);
        description.setText(event.description);


        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(event.logo, Base64.DEFAULT); //convert to byteArray
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,decodedString.length);
        clubImg.setImageBitmap(decodedByte); //reference to image view and let image view show the image

        byte[] decodedString2 = Base64.decode(event.eventImage, Base64.DEFAULT); //convert to byteArray
        Bitmap decodedByte2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString2, 0,decodedString2.length);
        eventImg.setImageBitmap(decodedByte2); //reference to image view and let image view show the image

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmant_custom_home, container, false);

    populateNewsfeed();

    return view;

}

public void populateList() {

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(HomeFragment.this.getActivity(), events);
    ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lvNewsfeed1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public void populate() {

JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() //get the JSONObject
  {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


        for (int j = 0; j < response.length(); j++) {
            try {
                JSONObject temp=response.getJSONObject(j); //get each object
                if (temp.getString("eventImage") == ""){ //if it is null
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(HomeFragment.this.getActivity()); 
                    View theInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null); 
                    ImageView eventImg = (ImageView) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.eventImg);
                    eventImg.getDrawable().equals(null); //the corresponding ImageView will be null
                    if(eventImg.getDrawable() == null){
                        eventImg.setVisibility(View.GONE); //View is GONE
                    }
                    else{
                        eventImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //View is VISIBLE
                    }
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
            populateList();
    }
```

ListView layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mbdp.kampungsg.kampungsg3.Home.HomeFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/lvNewsfeed1">

    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_home layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mbdp.kampungsg.kampungsg3.Home.HomeFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/stroke_bg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/clubName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Community Club Name"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <Button
                            android:text="Join"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_width="108dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/join" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/svNewsfeed"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="7.28">

            <TextView
                android:text="Description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/eventImg" />

        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I make it work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if it is null`... That is not a null check

Comment: What happens after running the existing code ? Please specify

Comment: @tahsinRupam nothing happens.. no error, no nothing. the ImageView is still there

Comment: See where you have `convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventImg);`? Why are you not controlling the visibility of that?

Answer (score 0):

First, get your null checks correct.

```
eventImg.getDrawable().equals(null); //the corresponding ImageView will be null
if(eventImg.getDrawable() == null){
```

The first line does nothing. The second line is correct.

```
temp.getString("eventImage")  == ""){ //if it is null
```

That isn't a null check. Also not a valid string comparison.

You can use `isEmpty` method in Java, **but** there actually is null values for JSON, or your key value could not exist at all.

So, `temp.optString("eventImage")` might be more correct

---

Anyway, you have a JSONArray, so updating one single `eventImg` variable in a loop from a layout that **you never display** seems like the wrong idea.

Your `JsonArrayRequest` should be adding elements to some Adapter that's set to a ListView, not trying to inflate a Fragment layout

**Instead**, don't control the imageview from the JSON data. You need to parse the JSON into an Event, then store the empty string in your Event object, and **in the adapter**, you need to set the imageview to be GONE when that string is null or empty.

---

Sidenote: it's confusing when you name things `R.layout.fragment_` and load that into an adapter because that View isn't (typically) being shown as a Fragment..

Comment: i've replaced `temp.getString("eventImage")  == "")` to `temp.optString("eventImage").equals("")` but the ImageView still doesn't seem to be gone? My `JsonArrayRequest` is adding elements to an adapter that's set to a ListView. I am inflating the Fragment layout only to get the id of the ImageView, which is eventImg. Now I feel that the problem may lie at the retrieving of Id, am i getting it correctly?

Comment: Like I said, you never display the inflated layout, so you probably **are** setting an Imageview to GONE, but you would never see it... Basically, you're finding the view incorrectly

Comment: And nothing in your code adds to any adapter, so please edit your question with a [mcve] of what the problem youre trying to solve

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited my question with the codes

Comment: Updated my answer at the end

Comment: I just saw @cricket_007's Sidenote. It's also confusing that the layout is set to match_parent. This looks like the layout for the whole Fragment and not the layout for each Event in the Adapter. See my comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42458242/set-imageview-to-be-gone-when-the-retrieved-json-object-is-null/42459441#comment72069824_42458500)

Answer (score 0):

As @cricket_007 pointed out, this block of code doesn't make much sense.

- First, if you consider empty string ("") to be the same as null, then I would recommend using `TextUtils.isEmpty(temp.getString("eventImage"))`.
- Second, it looks like you're trying to check if eventImg.getDrawable() is null, but nowhere in this code are you setting a drawable to eventImg, so this is always true/false. I think you're trying to do something like this:

  ```
  try {
      JSONObject temp = response.getJSONObject(j);

      LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(HomeFragment.this.getActivity());
      View theInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
      ImageView eventImg = (ImageView) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.eventImg);

      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(temp.getString("eventImage"))) {
          eventImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          // Do something
      } else {
          eventImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          // Do something
      }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

Comment: How many "event"s are there? Is "eventImage" null for each "event"? I see that you're inflating R.layout.fragment_home, but that sounds like it belongs to the entire fragment, not to an individual event; there is probably only one eventImg, which is getting overridden for each "event". If that is the correct layout, then maybe try setting the width &/ height to wrap_content instead of match_parent.

Comment: In other words, probably only the first or the last "event" is being displayed.

Answer (score -1):

You should do it like this.

```
if(temp.has("eventImage"){
    if(!temp.isNull("eventImage"){
        //Show Image
    }else{
        //Hide image
    }
}else{
    //Do Something else
}
```